# Django + Python Reference related data from Q Object

Tags: python, django

I have two models and a Q object.

How can I retrieve the related data (the field called GROUP) and add it into my serialized result set shown below?

Thank you in advance!

Model A

```
class WaiverAdult(models.Model):

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    middle_initial = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
```

Model B

```
class CheckIns(models.Model):

    adult = models.ForeignKey(
        WaiverAdult, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name='adult_checkin')
    checkin = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    checkout = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    group = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Query

```
group_adults = serializers.serialize('jsonl', WaiverAdult.objects.filter(
                Q(adult_checkin__checkin__gte=today()) & Q(adult_checkin__group__exact=group)), fields=('first_name', 'last_name'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can annotate this, with:

```
from django.db.models import Value

group_adults = serializers.serialize(
    'jsonl',
    WaiverAdult.objects.filter(
        adult_checkin__checkin__gte=today(), adult_checkin__group=group
    ).annotate(group=Value(group)),
    fields=('first_name', 'last_name', 'group'),
)
```

Comment: I receive Q object has no attribute annotate.

Comment: @cbirch: in the answer, there is no `Q` object, since for this condition, you do *not* need one, the `.annotate(..)` is called on the *result* of `.filter(...)`, not on the `Q` object.